# Mysql and LDML (accended characters same as latin1 ones)

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

I am using utf8_slovenian_ci as my collation of a column and table. Everything is fine except č and c are treated as distinct characters (and other 2 slovenian specific characters).

They are different in sorting and meaning! But for search reasons on mobile phones it is hard to select č so I would like that non ascented characters behave as ascented ones:

c=č
s=š
z=ž

And vice versa, case insensitive.

I read about expanding the collation using LDML in mysql, but I am unable to make "bograč" = "bograc" in search engine.

Can anybody help me?

**UPDATE**

To simplify question, is it possible to make c=č for search and č is after c in ordering by using LDML? Can I modify the built in collation or is it necessary to make a new one?

**UPDATE 2**

My simplified query without search (all recipes by name for example) is:

```
SELECT * from recipes order by RecipeName COLLATE 'utf8_slovenian_ci' asc limit 5
```

I get explain:

```
Rows: 20.000, Extra: Using filesort
```

If I do not use the slovenian collation (I have general_ci now on RecipeName) I get:

```
Rows: 5, Extra: Using Index
```

If I search with WHERE LIKE='%soup%' I still get filesort on 20.000 rows, because it seems mysql filesorts on the whole results set.

So is the only way to have sorting on column RecipeName to use 2 columns, one general_ci and one slovenian_ci and use one for searching (as part of my fulltext search - this example is simplified), and the other one for sorting when I would like to order by RecipeName? Or would this still filesort the whole 20.000 recipes?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test, but the `utf8_general_ci` collation is accent insensitive and should do the search the way you want.

For optimum performance, you could create a separate column in your table that is `utf8_general_ci`  and search in that:

```
 real_column     search_column
 -----------------------------------
 bograč          bograč
```

Then the following should work:

```
 SELECT real_column FROM table WHERE search_column = "bograc"

 > bograč
```

Alternatively, a COLLATE should work (but slooooooow!). Something like this:

```
 SELECT real_column FROM table
 WHERE real_column COLLATE utf8_general_ci = "bograc";
```

Comment: I know about that. Problem is the sort order of our characters would not work then... I am searching using more than one column so making 2 columns is impractical. How about making all  databse columns general_ci and using slovenian_ci for sort only? Would using slovenian_ci slow down thins enourmously? I need this only when sorthing using alphabet.

Comment: But I think the sort same characters could be done using Mysql and LDML which would be a better option but I don't know how to make c=C=č=Č for example for search only.

Comment: I don't know what you mean (but then I don't know what LDML is.)

Comment: Using your idea returns: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1' but I use utf8 as my character set ;-(

Comment: LDML is: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ldml-collation-example.html one can define own sorting or search definitions in utf8...

Comment: Ah, OK. Looks like it might be possible with LDML then (but I don't know how). Re the query, is your connection character set also UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

The `COLLATION` on a column is used for both searching (`WHERE ...`) and sorting (`ORDER BY`); there is no way to *efficiently* have two different collations for a single column.

As already mentioned, you can tack on `COLLATE ...` to use a different collation in one of the cases.  But this may not using the index.  However, if you are reading the entire table anyway, then tacking on `COLLATE ...` won't hurt performance much.  (Indexes are rarely used with you access 'most' of a table.)

As already mentioned, 2 columns is a possibility.  One would be for searching and have `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` and have its own `INDEX`.  The other would have the identical text, but would be `COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci` and have a separate index.  That *might* be useful for sorting.

How will the sorting be done?  Will you fetch the whole table?  (See my note above.)  Or will you filter down to 20 rows, then sort them in the 'correct' Slovenian way?  Sorting 20 rows is not time consuming.  (See my other note above.)

So, I **recommend** declaring the column `utf8_general_ci` and include a `COLLATE` clause in queries that need sorting.  If that is not adequate, then provide specifics -- the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Then we can discuss this further.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html provides the details of the two collations (and others).  I see that `Ø` also acts like a separate letter, as with `Č`, `Š` and `Ž`.

**More**

As I understand your requirement, you (1) search all 20K rows with accent stripping, then (2) sort the subset using utf8_slovenian_ci collation.  Since step 1 is the more costly, setting the collation for it is better for overall performance.  If, for example, only 5 row need sorting, then applying `COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci` will be a small price to pay.

**More #2**

*My previous comments had not considered that the `WHERE` was using a leading wildcard.*

Let's say you have 20.000 rows and the query retrieves 500 rows.  For example:  `WHERE col LIKE '%soup%' ORDER BY col`.  The leading wildcard is an important factor in this scenario.

20.000 rows will be looked at to do the `WHERE`, *regardless* of the collations.  I do not know how much cost a `COLLATE` clause would be.  The cost of the leading wildcard is probably more than that of the collate.

The 500 rows may or may not use the index.  If the column declaration matches the collation desired for the `ORDER BY`, the optimizer *may* make use of the index.  (If the collation disagrees, it can't use the index for ordering.)

Since the declared collation might help with one (`WHERE` or `ORDER BY`) and hurt for the other, it is hard to predict which will be better.  I recommend trying both ways:

```
col VARCHAR ... COLLATE utf8_general_ci
WHERE col LIKE '%soup%'
    ORDER BY col COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci
-- versus --
col VARCHAR ... COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci
WHERE col LIKE '%soup%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
    ORDER BY col
```

On the other hand, if you have two columns:

```
col_for_display VARCHAR ... COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci
col_for_searching VARCHAR ... COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

then do this:

```
SELECT col_for_display
    WHERE col_for_searching LIKE '%soup%'
    ORDER BY col_for_display
```

That should use the index for the `WHERE` (but still scan the entire table because of the leading wildcard).  It cannot use any index for the `ORDER BY`, but `col_for_display` will know how to properly sort.

Again, I cannot predict whether this option is enough faster than the other two options.

Bottom line:  I see no way to get what you desire, not even with a new collation.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you. I have 20.000 data in a table and I need them sorted and shown by each 20 rows, yes (pagination). So I can not filter by general_CI and then sort using slovenian_ci this 20 records, I need to have the correct results from the 20.000. And yes, I tried using slovenian_ci on order by then the index is not used and it searches 20.000 results instead of 20 (using index).

Comment: My original question was not if I can use 2 different collations for search and order by, but if I can make a new collation with LDML changes in mysql that would sort č after c but still recognise them as the same characters in search? Because one can have primary, secondary and terciary differences so if I could somehow say c=č for search and č>c for order by that would be perfect. It would be like utf8_jerrry_ci collation, a new one.

Comment: There is no way for a single MySQL collation to act differently for searching than for sorting.

Comment: What you propose (searching using general_ci and sorting using slovenian_ci still has to sort using all results and I still get 10x slower search. I'll update my question with my query (simplified of course).

Comment: Thank you for your info. In fact I do not use even LIKE '%soup%' I use complicated queries using fulltext index on recipe name, ingredients. Collation is to costly to order by different collation ,-(